# Appium application automation testing issues of element size

Tags: windows, automation, appium, appium-desktop

We are doing Windows application automation using Appium. That application is developed under WPF Microsoft technology.

In Appium source response we got xml proper but not getting `x, y, height, width` of `tabItem` of tab control.

XML look like below

```
<Tab AcceleratorKey="" AccessKey="" AutomationId="MainTabControl" ClassName="TabControl" FrameworkId="WPF" HasKeyboardFocus="False" HelpText="" IsContentElement="True" IsControlElement="True" IsEnabled="True" IsKeyboardFocusable="True" IsOffscreen="False" IsPassword="False" IsRequiredForForm="False" ItemStatus="" ItemType="" LocalizedControlType="tab" Name="" Orientation="None" ProcessId="68888" RuntimeId="7.68888.15577129" x="8" y="41" width="1350" height="679" Selection="7.68888.32204626">
    <TabItem AcceleratorKey="" AccessKey="" AutomationId="" ClassName="TabItem" FrameworkId="WPF" HasKeyboardFocus="False" HelpText="" IsContentElement="True" IsControlElement="True" IsEnabled="True" IsKeyboardFocusable="False" IsOffscreen="True" IsPassword="False" IsRequiredForForm="False" ItemStatus="" ItemType="" LocalizedControlType="tab item" Name="Samba.Presentation.ClientLibrary.Modules.LoginModule.LoginView" Orientation="None" ProcessId="68888" RuntimeId="7.68888.61852681" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" IsSelected="False" SelectionContainer="{, TabControl, 7.68888.15577129}" IsAvailable="True" />
</Tab>
```

Appium gives `x, y, height, width` of `Tab` but not of `TabItem`.

So, we cannot click on that `Tab` item.

Comment: could you post your locator, how you are accessing the element ?

Comment: In the TabItem you can see AutomationId is blank and x, y, height, weight are zero

Comment: You can try with iOSNsPredicateString this link will help you https://appiumpro.com/editions/8

Comment: Given xml string is generated from appium itself only and it's windows desktop application.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the platform. Still, we can click on tab using X,Y coordinate of tab or you need write the xpath = "//Tab/TabItem[@Name, 'Samba.Presentation.ClientLibrary.Modules.LoginModule.LoginView']"

Comment: ok let me try same. Back very soon